# fullcalendar js doesnt render view on internet explorer 11

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I have a calendar with *fullcalendar.js*. It's work on chrome, but on Internet Explorer view doesn't render. Here is my code: I'm getting events from the server, and then rendering it with reRender function. Here is some code:

```
data.eventClick = (calEvent, jsEvent, view) => this.eventClick(calEvent)

data.eventResize = (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) =>
{
    this._taskService.updateTaskTime(event.start.format(), 
        event.end.format(), event.id, false);
};
data.dayClick = (date, jsEvent, view, resourceObj) =>
{
    if (this.view !== 'week')
    {
        this.newTask([], date);
    }
    else
    {
        date = moment(resourceObj.id + 'T' + date.clone().format().split('T')[1]);
        this.newTask([], date);
    }
};

data.editable              = true;
data.eventDurationEditable = true;

this.containerEl.fullCalendar(data);
this.containerEl.fullCalendar('option', 'locale', this.localeCode);
this.containerEl.fullCalendar('option', 'height', this.calendarHeight);
this.containerEl.fullCalendar('gotoDate', this.date);
```

Comment: did you make changes in polyfills.ts? check for.../** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/

Comment: yes I have added all pollyfills.

Comment: "doesn't render" isn't nearly enough info to be able to help you. Have you done any debugging, checked for script errors, network errors etc?

Comment: I fixed that problem, that was because calendar was in flexible element. but now I have another problem in IE11 in calendar scrollbar doesn't work.

Comment: again, "doesn't work" isn't an error message or problem statement that we can work with really.